# Confused about memory storage units

Tags: memory, operating-system, byte, bit

I'm reading this book 3 easy pieces by remzi. In chapter 18 paging introduction in the first paragraph it is written

> (real address spaces are much bigger, of course,
> commonly 32 bits and thus 4-GB of address space, or even 64 bits)

Now if 1 byte is 8 bits, shouldn't 32 bits be 32/8 4 bytes space? I have seen the math for getting the answer as 4GB

```
2^10 = 1KB
2^10 = 1MB
2^10 = 1GB
```

But then this is assuming 2^1 = 1B, But isn't this simply wrong?

What am I missing? What does my answer (4Bytes) represent here?

This question is related [How many bits are needed to address this much memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543763/how-many-bits-are-needed-to-address-this-much-memory)

But doesn't address why my math is incorrect. (OP there also has the exact same confusion).
Lets say that I change the word size to 64MB (wild I know). Then number of words is 1. According to the answers, number of bits would be 2^0 = 1, 0 bits? Then where and when do we use the fact that 1 byte = 8 bits?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Today, RAM is byte addressable. Each address put on the address bus returns 1 byte. If you have 32 bits, the amount of different addresses that you can come up with is 2^32 = 4,294,967,296. Since you can have that much different addresses, then you can address that much bytes. In terms of bytes, this amount of bytes is called 4 GB.

Comment: What does returning 1 byte physically mean? Like what does it actually return? Voltage can be one answer but can it be explained further to help visualize?

Comment: What I wrote is quite simplified. Today, desktop RAM is mostly DIMMS for which the standard is DDR3 or 4 and is developed by JEDEC. DIMMS have sets of pins on which you apply voltage for a certain amount of clock cycles. The A pins are address pins but they are combined with B pins. The CPU selects a DRAM bank with B pins and A pins address this memory bank. The DIMM  then applies its output voltage on output data pins called DQ pins. The DIMM returns 64 bits. The CPU can ignore portions of it if the code asks only for 8 bits let's say. Or, it loads it in the cache.

Comment: So that im guessing that some combination of 64 bits returned by DIMM is what we call a byte? In a byte addressable machine?

Comment: Hum, in a write operation I'd say you'll write a full 64 bits but each adress represents the beginning of a 64 bits range that you can increment in one byte steps. I cannot confirm but, maybe read the standard for more info or post another question on electronics.stackexchange.com.